# Sourcing High Conductor Count Cable

Tags: connector, cables, cable-assemblies

I need to run approximately 25 feet (8m) of cabling up to a project box containing an array of ultrasonic sensors. (note, I was not in charge of the design of this project, if it had been up to be I'd have gone with an array of I2C sensors and just used a single bus, but it's beyond that point now, and I'm just responsible for helping them run the cable). The sensors are low-voltage (5V), and of negligible current consumption (perhaps 100mA total), and the cable will be stored indoors, and will be stationary once installed.

I'm having trouble finding a way to source/buy some kind of cable that will have enough conductors (for a reasonable cost, ie. sub $250). I'll need 30 conductors total. None of the common options (VGA, DVI, etc) have a high enough pin count, so I thought I'd use a DSUB37 cable, with panel mount connectors on either end, but I've had no luck finding a cable of that length.

Would any of you have ideas for solutions?

Comment: Sourcing - like in "buying"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have specified. Edited the post.

Comment: So, do you **need** panel mount connectors? Is the cable exposed to the elements? Highest voltage and current? Does it need to flex at all?

Comment: Cable will be stored indoors in a cable trough, and will be stationary once installed, but it will need to bend during installation. Low voltage, low current (5V, a few mA). Panel mount connectors would be a plus, as it would make the installation easier than hard-wiring everything into the project box and running the cable afterwards.

Comment: How many units are you making? just one? And how do you feel about putting connectors on the end of cables yourself rather than buying complete?

Comment: Just the one, it's for an art-piece installation. I don't think that would be a problem, barring the need for exotic/uncommon crimp tools

Comment: With either I2C or unterminated single ended TTL signals over 8m of cable "in random environment" I'd make bloody sure you're not held responsible for glitches. That said, Mouser, DigiKey, Farnell, all have cable and connectors, which IMHO make this boil down to a very straightforward shopping question.

Comment: I'd try looking for old external SCSI cables / Centronic cables. Those had plenty pins (more than 30 I think)...

Comment: 50 pair Cat 3 phone cable, and terminate it yourself.

Comment: Why not just use multiple Ethernet cables, they are very cheap.  https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=27483

Comment: This is an  honest recommendation: test with two or three sensors with just about any cable that you have lying around first whether that distance works at all. 5V and *cumulative* 100 mA over 30 conductors sounds like a lot of chance for interference to ruin your day.

Comment: I also like @JackCreasey's approach: Cables are cheap, shielded, and also, a small patch panel on each end is all you need to connect your free-flying 30 conductors. You can also just waltz in and buy a roll of ribbon cable.

Comment: also, have you consider 2× VGA? Those are cheap and should have 15 separate conductors (DO CHECK! Some cheapskates might have tied different signal grounds together.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Digi-Key or Mouser have literally hundreds of various multi-conductor cables, twisted pairs, shielded, or individual, up to 600 conductors (300 twisted pairs). What the heck?

Comment: Somehow I'd forgotten ribbon cable exists...
With digikey/mouser my problem was more the fact that the cable assemblies weren't long enough for the full run (less than 20 feet usually).

I definitely won't be held responsible for any interference, I've already asked the people working on the project to test their sensors together with long lengths of cable to ensure that they will work properly.

Comment: Also to add, if I wanted to buy just cable from digikey, and add connectors on myself, it'd be a tad out of budget:
(eg: https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/cables-wires/multiple-conductor-cables/473?k=&pkeyword=&pv316=62&pv316=42&pv316=71&pv316=72&pv316=44&pv316=73&pv316=35&pv316=74&pv316=36&pv316=58&pv316=75&pv316=46&FV=ffe001d9&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&nstock=1&pageSize=25)

Sorry if I've caused confusion!

Comment: If you go to that digikey link of yours and just sort the table by price, the top of the list is a 36-conductor cable for $6.38/ft. Does that really blow your budget?

Comment: Start looking for surplus cables on the internet. Here, for instance, https://www.electronicsurplus.com/wire-cable you can get 20-conductor twisted pair for 65 cents a foot. Use two lengths with 25-pin D connectors. And yes, you'll have to do your own connector assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked Mouser or other online sources? [This 30-conductor ribbon cable](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Temp-Flex/100057-0182?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsJiFh04Lj2riYM0D38ayB%2FXZKZrbVqb%2FY%3D) is ~US$11/ft (~US$35/m). If you need more protection than the cable itself, it could be run inside heat-shrink tubing, or even bicycle inner-tube.

Comment: Hadn't considered ribbon cable, I don't know how that slipped my mind. That could work! Thank you